# how to capture IP address from info

Tags: linux, awk, sed, regular-expression, curl

by the following api we can get the info about master1/2 machines

```
curl -sH "X-Requested-By: ambari" -u "admin"":""admin" -i http://192.23.39.2:8080/api/v1/hosts?fields=Hosts/host_name,Hosts/ip | egrep "master1|master3"  | grep http  
      "href" : "http://192.23.39.2:8080/api/v1/hosts/master1.usa14.com",
      "href" : "http://192.23.39.2:8080/api/v1/hosts/master3.usa14.com",
```

now I update the api to get only the IP's of master1/3

```
curl -sH "X-Requested-By: ambari" -u "admin"":""admin" -i http://192.23.39.2:8080/api/v1/hosts?fields=Hosts/host_name,Hosts/ip | egrep "master1|master3"  | grep http | sed s'/\/\// /g' | sed s'/:/ /g' | awk '{print $3}'

192.23.39.2
192.23.39.2
```

but my api isn't so elegant

any other suggestion how to capture the ip's ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by simply by using `awk` string manipulation functions

```
awk -F'/[/]?' '$NF ~ /^(master1|master3).*/{ n=split($2,arr,":"); print arr[1] }'
```

Answer (score 0):

using grep :

```
  grep 'master[1,3]' | grep -oE "([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Done by using sed command and it worked fine

command

```
 sed -e "s/.*\:\///g" -e "s/:.*//g" -e "s/\///g" filename
```

output

```
192.23.39.2
192.23.39.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Done by using python too

```
import re
p=re.compile(r'[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*')
k=open('filename','r')
for i in k:
    h=re.search(p,i)
    print h.group()
```

output

```
192.23.39
192.23.39
```